# Dynamically resize textarea upwards

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a `textarea` that automatically re-sizes upwards. I've got a bit of code that works fine at resizing by pushing the bottom down but I need it so all the content in the text area moves up to reveal a new line and the base of the text-area is fixed in its position. (Let me know if I didn't explain that very well!) The code I have so far is:

```
document.getElementById('texttype').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.style.height = 0;
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
}, false);
```

Comment: What you mean by resize upwards?

Comment: What do you want this example to do ? It's working probably right: http://jsfiddle.net/cdDWz/

Comment: For example on Facebook if you reach the bottom of the text area for a status update it adds more room below what is already written by expanding the area downwards. In that instance the top of the text area is in a fixed position. I want to do a similar thing but have the bottom of the text area fixed and give more room by pushing the text that's been written up to reveal a new, empty line.

Comment: Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/afQmf/), you mean?

Comment: Exactly like that! I knew it would be something really simple - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered by [Tewathia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003352/tewathia) in the comments but I thought I should add an answer so I could check it off. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afQmf/

HTML:

```
<div><textarea name="" id="texttype"></textarea></div>
```

CSS:

```
    div {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

   #texttype {
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    document.getElementById('texttype').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.style.height = 0;
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

automatically re-sizes up- and downwards
HTML:

```
<textarea onkeyup="autoGrow(this)"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
function autoGrow (oField) {
    if (oField.scrollHeight > oField.clientHeight) {
        oField.style.height = oField.scrollHeight "px";
    }else{
        oField.style.height = 0+"px";
        oField.style.height = oField.scrollHeight "px";
    }
}
```